# Doubly Linked List Insert Function C++

Tags: c++, doubly-linked-list

So basically, I'm trying to make a function that will insert values into a doubly-linked list in order.

This function works up until the 3rd value, where it seems like it gets stuck in the `while` loop:

```
template <class T>
void List<T>::insert_end(T item) {
    node<T> *newNode = new node<T>;
    newNode -> data = item;

    if (head == NULL && tail == NULL){
        head = newNode;
        tail = newNode;
        newNode -> next = NULL;
        newNode -> previous = NULL;
        ++len;
    }

    else {
        node<T> *cursor = head;
        while(cursor->next != NULL){
            cursor = cursor -> next;
        }
        cursor -> next = newNode;
        newNode -> previous = cursor;
        ++len;
    }
}
```

Comment: Time to (learn to) use a debugger and step through your code

Comment: By the way, what's the point of having a `tail` node when you don't use it for inserting at the end?

Comment: I highly recommend getting your linked list to work with a fixed data type, such as integers, before converting to template.  A lot easier to debug.

Comment: Consider the while loop's end condition.  Also, isn't that what tail is for?

Comment: Thanks for the feedback guys, I made some adjustments. :)

Comment: You edited the code in your question, altering the semantics of the question. You should have posted the new code as an answer instead, if you wanted to show it (though it had new bugs in it). I have reverted the edit now to maintain the original question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function is more complicated than it need to be.

For starters,  the whole point of having a `tail` pointer is for providing easy insertions and traversals at the end of the list, but you are completely ignoring `tail`.  When the list is not empty, your `while` loop is traversing the list from front to back trying to find the last node in the list - the node that `tail` is already pointing at.  And then when you add the new node to the list, you are not updating `tail` to point at the new node.

You tried to edit the function to remove the `while` loop (good), but you introduced some new bugs.  You were no longer assigning `newNode->previous` if the list already has any nodes in it.  And worse, you were setting `tail->next` to `head`, which is just plain wrong, as it creates an endless loop for any code that tries to traverse the list from front to back.

The function can be greatly simplified to the following:

```
template <class T>
void List<T>::insert_end(T item)
{
    node<T> *newNode = new node<T>;
    newNode->data = item;
    newNode->next = NULL;
    newNode->previous = tail;

    if (!head)
        head = newNode;

    if (tail)
        tail->next = newNode;
    tail = newNode;

    ++len;
}
```

An `insert_front()` implementation would be equally as simple:

```
template <class T>
void List<T>::insert_front(T item)
{
    node<T> *newNode = new node<T>;
    newNode->data = item;
    newNode->next = head;
    newNode->previous = NULL;

    if (head)
        head->previous = newNode;
    head = newNode;

    if (!tail)
        tail = newNode;

    ++len;
}
```

That being said, if you can, you really should use the STL's `std::list` class instead of a manual list implementation.  If you want to keep using your own class, you can easily encapsulate `std::list`, eg:

```
#include <list>

template<typename T>
class List
{
private:
    std::list<T> m_list;
    ...

public:
    ...
    void insert_front(const T &item);
    void insert_end(const T &item);
    ...
};

template<typename T>
void List<T>::insert_front(const T &item)
{
    m_list.push_front(item);
}

template<typename T>
void List<T>::insert_end(const T &item)
{
    m_list.push_back(item);
}
```

Comment: The code can be greatly reduced to the following: `std::list<T> list; list.push_back(item);`

Comment: @Puppy: I don't disagree, but at the same time this is clearly a learning exercise, so chances are the OP is not allowed to use `std::list`.

Comment: Thank you, that works brilliantly and also helped me with my remove function. Question though, do you not need to add tail -> next = head at the end to insure it remains a doubly linked list?

Using std::list is not an option (wish it was)

Comment: "*`tail->next = head` at the end to insure it remains a doubly linked list*" - ABSOLUTELY NOT! That is not what makes a list be a double-linked list. If you did that, front-to-back traversals will never find a `NULL` pointer to end the traversal, thus an endless loop. `head->previous` and `tail->next` *MUST ALWAYS* be `NULL`. In a double-linked list, nodes have both `previous` and `next` pointers, thus bi-directional (double) links between adjacent nodes. In a single-linked list, nodes have either a `previous` or `next` pointer only, thus a uni-directional (single) link between adjacent nodes.

Comment: That's really interesting. My professor explicitly stated that the nature of a doubly linked list would require

1<->5<->9<->12
And then have 12 linked back to 1. 

As of right now, that's how I have it, and when iterating through I keep track of the size of the linked list to end it. 

My next challenge is going to be using what's here to create a tree..lol

I'm not saying you're wrong by any means, and your solutions are awesome. :)

Comment: Then your professor is wrong, or more likely you just misunderstood him/her. `1<->5<->9<->12` (more accurately, `null<-1<->5<->9<->12->null`) would indeed create a double-linked list, but having `12->1` would create a circular list (draw it out on paper). Don't create a circular list unless you really need it (for circular buffers). Don't use the list `size` to manage traversals (which will not work anyway if traversals start in the middle of the list). Stop the traversal when you reach the `head` or `tail` node.

Comment: A tree is basically 2 double-linked lists on top of each other, where each node has 4 pointers, `previous` and `next` for movement between sibling nodes on the same branch, and `parent` and `first_child` for movement between branches.